# How to debug failing commands in a stuck pipeline in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've set up a repository in a local Gitlab (Community Edition) install, and a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the repo root.

The file contains instructions to deploy a web site through FTP on commit. It's supposed to call `lftp` and mirror the new revision's contents to a remote server.

However, when I commit to the repo, the commit stays on `pending` and `stuck` forever:

[image]

I have to assume there's something wrong with the `lftp` command in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file - but I can't for the life of me find out how to debug this.

Where can I see the full command string (with `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` and the other variables replaced) so I can run it myself from the command line, or at least see the error messages returned by the `lftp` call?

I can't find anything in GitLab's UI, nor in `/var/syslog`. Googling doesn't seem to be helpful, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the status (pending) then on the step that is pending, you should see the full output of your commands

Comment: Weird, I did try that and didn't see anything, I'll check again when I get back to work.

Comment: Indeed! Clicking on the button with the process name and the "pending" status got me detailed info.